# Qt 5.4/Windows Phone/WinRT: Ignore SSL/HTTPS errors

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I want to connect to a device using a secure socket (https://10.10.10.10:443) to Windows Phone and WinRT 8.1. The device has an invalid certificate (e.g. the name is not correct) but the device's certificate cannot be changed.
On most platforms this SSL error can be simply ignored. But on Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 (Store/Modern/Metro) the system must be explicitely instructed to accept a connection when the error occurs, else the following error is returned:

```
The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value.
```

Please check the **EDIT** below.

The following C# code works fine and allows a connection to a host with invalid certificates:

```
// 1.) Register certificate in store
System.Uri certificateFile = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom_certificate.cer");
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(certificateFile);
Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer certBlob = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate rootCert = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate(certBlob);
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStore trustedStore = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities;
trustedStore.Add(rootCert);

// 2.) Connect to host
StreamSocket tcp = new StreamSocket();
tcp.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
tcp.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
tcp.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
await tcp.ConnectAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName("10.10.10.10"), "443", SocketProtectionLevel.SslAllowNullEncryption);
// Success
```

Now I want to have the same behaviour using Qt 5.4:

```
QFile certFile(":/resources/custom_certificate.cer");
certFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly); // ok
QSslCertificate cert(&certFile, QSsl::Der);
qDebug() << "Certificate loaded: " << (!cert.isNull()); // true -> so certificate is loaded

QSslSocket* socket = new QSslSocket(this);
socket->ignoreSslErrors();
socket->addCaCertificate(cert);
connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(tcp_connected()));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(tcp_readyRead()));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(tcp_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
socket->connectToHostEncrypted(host, port, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

void Test::tcp_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError err)
{
    qDebug() << "SSL error: " << err; // prints 13 which is "SslHandshakeFailedError"
}
```

But I am always getting this `The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value.` error.

Is there something wrong with my Qt code?

**EDIT:** I could reduce the relevant code:

C# (working):

```
StreamSocket tcp = new StreamSocket();
await tcp.ConnectAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName(host), "443");
tcp.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
await tcp.UpgradeToSslAsync(SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12, new Windows.Networking.HostName(host));
```

Qt 5.4 (not working):

```
QSslSocket* socket = new QSslSocket(this);
QList<QSslError> ignoreErrors;
ignoreErrors.append(QSslError::HostNameMismatch);
socket->setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(tcp_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
socket->connectToHostEncrypted(host, port, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

void Test::tcp_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError err)
{
    qDebug() << "SSL error: " << err; // prints 13 which is "SslHandshakeFailedError"
}
```

Regards,

Comment: did you try adding a: ``connect(socket,SIGNAL(sslErrors()),socket,SLOT(ignoreSslErrors()))``? May the WinPhone implementation still bugs on presetting the ignore spec. As per documentation it should be fine to connect the sslErrors signal to the ignore-slot.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added ``connect(socket,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),socket,SLOT(ignoreSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));`` but the error remains. I also checked the Qt source code (e.g. ``qsslsocket_winrt.cpp`` and companions). I think the problem is that the implementation first connects to the host and later calls the WinRT method ``socket->UpgradeToSslAsync`` (in ``continueHandshake()``). I think that the WinRT implementation must first (before ANY connection) install certificates and ignore error flags.